# Make element scroll without fixed position setting

Tags: css

Is there a way to make an element scroll with the background without giving it a fixed position? So it won't cause problems when resizing the window?
the element I am talking about is referred to in the css as follows.

```
#logo {
        margin: 20px auto;
        width:355.2px;
        height:148.8px;
```

Comment: What do you mean by ***with the background***

Comment: I mean that when the body scrolls, or the div that contains the logo div scrolls, the logo will scroll up and down with it, basically, but I don't wanna give a fixed position cos it will mess everything up when I resize the window.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using a position fixed for it.  in order to fix your problem with the resize you can use screen query to obey your needs

Comment: Can you tell me more about it? I have been around these languages only for a week.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be accomplished without using position fixed, in order to fix your problem with the resize you'll need to use screen query for it. Here's an example of how to use it on your style.css file and a [list of default screen sizes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

**=== UPDATED FOR YOUR NEEDS ===**

In order to align your logo on the middle of the screen and not display it on smaller screens as you requested on the comments you'll need to use a position absolute for your #logo, to make it fixed while you scroll the page, wrap it inside of a fixed div. Here's the trick

```
/* Your normal css goes here */
.logoContainer{
    position:fixed;
}
#logo {
    left:50%; /* this puts your logo on the middle of the screen */
    width:38px;
    margin-left:-19px; /* this needs to be half of the width */
    position:absolute;
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Your fix for smaller screen sizes example*/
    #logo {
        display:none; /* this tells your div to not display */
    }
}
```

**Here's an [online example](http://jsfiddle.net/hxc0djz4/)**

Comment: I tried this, thought I was wondering, maybe is there any attribute that gives the containing div the ability to make the contained give scroll with it? So I am basically looking for something to apply to the containing div rather than the logo itself.

Comment: Or maybe can you explain how this works. Cos I want the logo to be perfectly in the top middle when the pic is fully extended, so I don't want it to display at all when I resize. This is the way I edited do far, but results aren't those I hoped: #logo {
  top:20px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-177.6px;
  width:355.2px;
  height:148.8px;
  position:fixed;
 }
 
 @media screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    #logo {
  margin left:-177.6px;
    }

Comment: I've edited my answer @GiorgioVitanza , check out the online example I've added. Resize the window with the result to see it in action. To not display it at all as you said, that's up to you on what you put inside of the screen query whether you want to display it or not or give any other style