# Wordpress div responsive on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I customized the home template of this photography site to include 4 divs to highlight the 4 major sections of the photographer's portfolio. They are not responsive when sizing the browser or on mobile devices. What do I have to include in order to make them responsive? (media queries min max, not certain)

site: http://jeremy.insctest1.com

one of the divs:

div  onclick="window.location='/portfolio/architecture/architecture/';" id="item1" style="width:453px; height:400px; background-image:url('http://jeremy.insctest1.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/arch-home.png'); float: left; margin: 0 20px 20px 0;">

```
                div class="item-title" style="width:inherit; position: relative; top:350px; height: 50px; background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom ,rgba(232,232,232,0.8) 0%, rgba(214,214,214,0.8) 100%);">

            div class='b' style="          
height: 50px;     
width: 453px;     
display: table-cell;     
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;">Architecture</div>
                </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: media queries will do. here, I just answered a similiar question involving [media queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144049/make-element-scroll-without-fixed-position-setting/29144714#29144714)

Comment: Could you please format your posted HTML? Also, it does not match the equivalent "portfolio architecture" `<div>`  found at the hyperlink.

Comment: im new to stack, so when i copy pasted the code it wouldn't show it all, so i deleted some div tags so people could see it

Comment: @Chun i am not certain on where to put those media queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you'll need to reorganize your code and add a class which will be able to do the same for all of the divs containing the images assuming that's what you want to make responsive, so you don't need to create a class for each one of these elements, then I'd recommend exchange the `onclick="window.location='/portfolio/architecture/architecture/';"` for `a href` because you're just using this to navigate through pages so no need to `onclick` href is the way to do it. all combined should look somethin like this:

```
<a href="/portfolio/architecture/architecture/" id="item" class="float-right">
    <img src="http://jeremy.insctest1.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/arch-home.png" width="253" height="200"/>
</a>
<a href="/portfolio/architecture/architecture/" id="item" class="float-left">
    <img src="http://jeremy.insctest1.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/arch-home.png" width="253" height="200"/>
</a>
```

and then put your css on your style.css file of the theme which will look something like this:

```
#item {
    width:453px;
    height:400px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.float-left {float: left;}
.float-right {float: right;}
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Your fix for smaller screen sizes example*/
    #item {
       width:253px;
       height:200px;
    }
    #item img {
       width:253px;
       height:200px;
    }
}
```

If using images as divs background is still a priority you use the code like this instead:

```
<a href="/portfolio/architecture/architecture/">
    <div id="item1" class="responsive float-left"></div>
</a>
<a href="/portfolio/architecture/architecture/">
    <div id="item2" class="responsive float-right"></div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
#item1 {
    background-image: url('http://jeremy.insctest1.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/arch-home.png');
}
#item2 {
    background-image: url('http://jeremy.insctest1.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/portrait-home.png');
}
.responsive {
    width:453px;
    height:400px;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
.float-left {float: left;}
.float-right {float: right;}
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Your fix for smaller screen sizes example*/
    .responsive {
        width:253px;
        height:200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a great, but I am having issue now working in the opacity div i have with the name in the div. ex: Architecture

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what's the problem you are facing. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: i attempted to use your fix, and it works for the most part, if you refer to the url, I have a div that has the title of each category, and has an opacity, i am attempting to figure out how to style that with your fix

Comment: then put the opacity you want for the smaller screens inside of the media query. For example: `.item-title{ opacity:1;}` here's an [online example](http://jsfiddle.net/4yah5mxz/). but I think your opacity is created by the rgb background image color, so putting something like this `.item-title{  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom ,rgba(232, 232, 232, 1) 0%, rgba(214, 214, 214, 1) 100%);}` inside the media query will do the job if you're looking to remove the transparency

Comment: thank you that seems to work, with one issue. on firefox and IE the opacity label (lets call it) appears at the top of the div, not at the bottom. It shows correctly in Chrome at the bottom of the div

Comment: well this is not caused by the code I gave you in the answer, to me it seems to work just fine on the link you have on your question which is: **http://jeremy.insctest1.com**. I'd have to see an online example of this and try different things and see what's causing this issue. but I'm assuming exchange `top: 350px;` for `bottom:0;` in your class **.item** and give a `position:relative;` for the container in this case would be the class **.responsive** would do the job